# jquery stop element from hiding on click

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function that inserts an animated "working" image, and then display "done!" after the POST is completed. However, I want this to occur in multiple places at once.

Example at: http://veretekk.com/developer/temp/

More detail is outlined at the page above, but basically the #dialog element is hiding when the button contained inside it is clicked. Also... the reason the jquery uses `.on` rather than `$(document).ready(function() {` is that this content can appear on my site after the DOM is loaded and thus needs to be available at all times. Help!

Comment: My guess is that the `$(".member_button_friend_"+user).html` removes the event target causing the `if ($("#dialog").is(":visible") ...` check to fail.  Instead of using `.html`, hide the input and use `.append`

Comment: I am not getting your problem correctly... When I click on the Ignore button nothing happens there is no image the button changes to done..but nothing else changes on the page...

Comment: My first suggestion would be to untangle your code by removing inline JavaScript.  Inline JavaScript is much more difficult to maintain and debug.  Instead of `onclick=FriendAction("USER")`, simply use `$('#dialog').on('click', '.ignorebutton', function() {})`.  Inside of the function, you can get the USER id from the dialog (a data element, or an element ID, etc).

Comment: Explosion Pills - that is my hunch as well, but how to fix it?
Scorpio - your connection is fast so the .post just completes before the animated image loads.
@Jeff B - I have removed the inline javascript. Still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a lot of your problem lies in the complicated way you are determining whether or not to hide the dialog.

Instead of trying to intercept each document click and determine its target, let jQuery handle the details:

```
$(document).on('click', function (event) {
    // If the document is clicked, hide the dialog
    $('#dialog').hide();
});

$(document).on('click', '#dialog', function (event) {
    // If the dialog is clicked, stop the propagation
    // of the click event to the document
    // The first handler will never be called
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Simplified demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/M93dZ/

Comment: Excellent - thank you! Using this and some more tweaking I should be able to get there...